# how to get rid of notification circle in right side of the screen?

Tags: amazon-fire-tv

I've looked online but wasn't able to find anything:

how do I get rid of this notification circle that is being displayed over the movie I'm watching? [image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not at all programming related

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This stuff comes from ES file explorer

Just go into this app > settings

Then there is an option that says logging floating window, you just need to disable that and you will get rid of this infernal bubble for good

Comment: What a terrible idea by ES file explorer. How on earth would that ever be a desirable feature??!